# ¿Cómo actualizo el atributo key de una tabla que es llave foránea de otra en MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Tengo mis tablas

**Cliente**

```
create table cliente(
       nombre varchar(100), 
       correo varchar(50), 
       password varchar(256), 
       primary key(correo)
);
```

**Contrata**

```
create table contrata(
       correo varchar(100), id varchar(50), 
       primary key(correo, id), 
       foreign key(correo) references cliente(correo), 
       foreign key(id) references proyecto(id)
);
```

Y mi trigger

```
DELIMITER $$
create trigger updateCliente
    before update
    on cliente for each row 
    BEGIN
    update  contrata set correo= new.correo where correo= old.correo;
    END$$
```

Pero al intentar hacer un update obtengo el problema

```
Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`solsoft`.`contrata`, CONSTRAINT `contrata_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`correo`) REFERENCES `cliente` (`correo`))
```

He buscado este problema y encuentro algunas soluciones que no me han servido, (otras como la de SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; la omití, ya que lo que busco es hacerlo de la manera correcta, usando llaves foráneas, no saltármelas)

Comment: Si contemplas modificar una columna que forma parte de la llave primaria, tal vez no debería no debería estar en la llave primaria; propagar ese cambio será un problema. El concepto es la inmutabilidad de las llaves primarias, por eso sería mejor tener un id númerico -que no cambiaría- como llave primaria, e incluso referenciar `contrata` a ese id, evitando duplicar el correo.

Comment: La cosa es que te está diciendo que ese email que estás poniendo al actualizar, NO existe en la tabla que referencias (cliente). Si esa validación no funciona para tus reglas de negocio, deberías considerar ajustes al diseño de la BD.

Comment: @Sal, tienes razón, eso haré para evitar este problema.

Comment: @Alfabravo, Ese código de error no salió porque el correo no estuviera.

Comment: @AlejandroSánchez no hay un registro en la tabla cliente con el correo que estás intentando usar en el update. Ese es el error. Estás actualizando la tabla hija ANTES DE actualizar el registro padre. Ese proceso en dos pasos no funciona. Sale porque el correo NO ESTÁ al momento de hacer el update en el trigger.